# how to check whether class exists if tab is active using cypress.io

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have a html code in below. How can i get if Test1 is clicked or Test2 is clicked

---

```html
<div>
       <li><a class="class1 active">Test1</a></li>
       <li><a class="class1">Test2</a></li>
    </div>
```

---

cy.get('//a[contains(text(),'Test1']').should('have.class').should('have.value','class1 active')

class would be changed to either (class1 active or class1) when clicked on Test1 or Test2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add an `.and()` to the assertion to check a second condition.

This should work as long as the subject does not change in the `.should()` assertion.

```js
cy.contains('a', 'Test1')
  .should('have.class', 'class1')
  .and('have.class','active')
```

You also do not need to use xpath any more, in fact for latest Cypress version it is no longer supported.

I added the Cypress command to use instead.